# ASP.NET fileupload in a usercontrol, get postedfile on postback

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, user-controls, postback

I am building a "multi site" with multiple languages. The number of languages is not fixed. So for all the management screens I bind a number of user controls to a tabpanel depending on the number of languages present.

```
  NewFileControl filePage = (NewFileControl)LoadControl("/backoffice/Controls/NewFileControl.ascx");
```

On postback I check if there is a Param containing the term "language" present to detect a new language and save an item per language. This works find with textboxs, dropdown and checkboxes.

The problem that I am facing is that on the current screen I am working on a "fileupload" is present. The postedfile is not in the Request.Params.

How can I get the posted file on PostBack when the fileuploader is in a usercontrol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Request.Files

Did the trick!